# How to use one of two locators based on other element text/presence in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How to use two locators for a element in robot framework? if locator 1 doesn't work , it should take locator 2. Below is a code example of what I'm trying but are unable to make work.

```
   ${button}  Element Should Contain  ${QAM}  Create button
    Run Keyword If  ${button}  click element  ${button1}
    ...  ELSE  click element  ${button2}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. In order to get the best response it is good to provide as much information about your situation as you can. Describe what you want to achieve, what code you have and the observed results. Please add the observed results. Is it an error, or other behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, with the only problem the keyword `Element Should Contain` being an assertion - if it passes, the case will continue, and if fails - the execution will stop. Being an assert it also doesn't return a value - in general there's nothing to do with such a value, the keyword itself controls the flow.

So to achieve what you need - get the assertion status, without stopping the execution, you have to wrap it in a special keyword just for that [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status). What it does is to call the wrapped keyword, and return boolean - `True`/`False` did it pass or fail. Here's your code with it:

```
${button}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Contain  ${QAM}  Create button
Run Keyword If  ${button}    click element  ${button1}
...  ELSE  click element  ${button2}
```